# Why do all of my cores clock up when I spin-loop on one core?

Tags: c, linux, cpu, multicore

When I run the following command on my laptop command line with no other interactive processes running (including this browser), I see that all cores maintain a clock speed around `500 Mhz`

```
watch -n 0.1 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz'
```

Then, I run the following program and observe that **all cores** jump to over 3 Ghz.

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void pinThreadToCore(int id) {
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(id, &cpuset);
    assert(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pinThreadToCore(atoi(argv[1]));
    while (1);
}
```

**Why do all cores increase their clock speed, rather than just one?**

I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` with `4.4.0-96-generic` on a dual-core laptop with 4 hyperthreads, in the answer is machine or OS-dependent.

Here is the output of `lscpu`.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 78
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               490.328
CPU max MHz:           3400.0000
CPU min MHz:           400.0000
BogoMIPS:              5615.82
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
```

Here is the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 78
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0xba
cpu MHz     : 497.109
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5615.82
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 78
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0xba
cpu MHz     : 736.312
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5615.82
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 78
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0xba
cpu MHz     : 499.515
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5615.82
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 78
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0xba
cpu MHz     : 499.078
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5615.82
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: I imagine that the clock speeds of the HyperThreaded logical CPUs cannot be different - the whole core is driven from a single clock. I'm not sure why the other core would follow.

Comment: I guess this is connected to affinity: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core

Comment: You're not saying what model of CPU you have.

Comment: @Ove, Sorry, it's an Intel i7; the version available with an X1 Carbon 4th Generation.

Comment: The i7 series is huge. What does lscpu or /proc/cpuinfo say?

Comment: @Ove, I've updated the question with the requested specs.

Comment: There is a related post [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/402516). The bottom of the line is that client (and more often than not, server) cpus run all the core at the same frequency even if the SW interface for single-core tuning exists. The Power Control Unit evidently takes a decision based on the requested P-state of all the cores (even in the presence of HWP, aka SpeedShift, as in your case). My Haswell exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Myself, I also have an older Intel CPU which I'm pretty sure shares the OS-requested frequency across all cores, but I don't know if that limitation still applies to newer Intel CPUs like yours. What I can suggest, though, is to install the program "i7z", which reports what frequencies your cores *actually* run on, which may very well be different from what Linux thinks.